# About CakePHP and google chart

Tags: php, cakephp, google-visualization

I've tried to use http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ixu38/2010/04/30/googlechart-api-helper but I have not managed to make it work.

1. I've created the helper `GoogleChartHelper` on `app-->View-->Helper` with the code.
2. I've created this function on my controller:

   ```
   public function chart() {
       $color = array(
           '#687e9b',
           '#c4ccd8',
       );

       $dataMultiple = array(array(0,1,2,3), array(4,5,6,7));

       $googleChart->setChartAttrs( 
           array(
               'type'      => 'bar-vertical',
               'title'     => '',
               'data'      => $dataMultiple,
               'size'      => array( 400, 200 ),
               'color'     => $color,
               'labelsXY'  => true,
               'min'       => array(min(rray(0,1,2,3)),min(array(4,5,6,7))),
               'max'       => array(max(array(0,1,2,3)),max(array(4,5,6,7))),
               'legend'    => array('2008', '2009')
           )
       );

   //  Print chart
       echo $googleChart;
   ```
3. Finally I put on the view this command:

`<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Chart'), '/users/chart'); ?>`

When i tried to make the chart, cakephp give me this error:

> Error: Call to a member function setChartAttrs() on a non-object

---

Where is the problem?

Comment: I guess you need to update your controller that you're using the GoogleCharts Helper.

Comment: how? I dont understand your request...

Comment: I put var $helpers = array('GoogleChart') on the controller... where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Try this helper for google chart](https://github.com/segy/GoogleChart/blob/master/View/Helper/GoogleChartHelper.php) and Paste it on `app/view/helper`
     And use code below

```
Controller:

public $helpers = array('GoogleChart');

View:

// example of bar chart
echo $this->GoogleChart->create()
    ->setType('bar', array('horizontal', 'grouped'))
    ->setSize(500, 400)
    ->setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    ->addData(array(1200.48, 432.3, 647.21, 635.2))
    ->addMarker('value', array('format' => 'f1', 'placement' => 'c'))
    ->addData(array(20, 42.3, 65.21, 95.2))
    ->addMarker('value', array('size' => 14, 'color' => '000000'))
    ->addAxis('x', array('labels' => array('jan 2012', 'feb 2012')))
    ->addAxis('y', array('axis_or_tick' => 'l', 'size' => 12));

// example of pie chart
echo $this->GoogleChart->create()
    ->setTitle('CHART TITLE', array('size' => 14, 'color' => '000000'))
    ->setType('pie', array('3d'))
    ->setSize(600, 300)
    ->setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
    ->addData(array(20, 35, 50, 10))
    ->setPieChartLabels(array('first', 'second', 'third', 'and so on...'));
```